# How to dynamical set de widgetDefinitions in malhar angular dashboard via rest client?

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-http, angular-module

I have installed [malhar-angular-dashboard](https://github.com/DataTorrent/malhar-angular-dashboard/) module and I want to populate some **widgetDefinitions** with my rest data.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="widgetCtrl">
   <div  dashboard-layouts="layoutOptions" class="dashboard-container"></div>
</div>
```

**widgetRestService**

```
.factory('widgetRestService',['$http','UrlService','$log','$q',
   function($http,UrlService,$log,$q){

  var serviceInstance = {};

  serviceInstance.getInfo = function(){
    var request = $http({method: 'GET', url: '/rest/widgets/getListInfoDashboards'})
      .then(function(success){
        serviceInstance.widgets = success.data;
        $log.debug('serviceInstance.widgets SUCCESS',serviceInstance.widgets);
      },function(error){
        $log.debug('Error ', error);
        $log.debug('serviceInstance.widgets ERROR',serviceInstance.widgets);
      });
    return request;
  };

  serviceInstance.getAllWidgets = function () {
    if (serviceInstance.widgets) {
      return serviceInstance.widgets;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  };

  return serviceInstance;

}])
```

My rest service returns me this **array of 3 objects** :`[{"name":"widgetList","title":" "},{"name":"widgetPie","title":" "},{"name":"widgetTable","title":" "}]`

**OtherService**

```
.factory("OtherService", ["widgetRestService", "$log", "$q",
   function (widgetRestService, $log, $q) {

  var deferred = $q.defer();

  widgetRestService.getInfo().then(function () {

    deferred.resolve(widgetRestService.getAllWidgets());
  });

  return deferred.promise;

}])
```

**Controller**

```
OtherService.then(function(response){
    $scope.layoutOptions = { // layout with explicit save
      storageId: 'demo-layouts-explicit-save',
      storage: localStorage,
      storageHash: 'fs4df4d51',
      widgetDefinitions:response , //must be a list
      defaultWidgets: [],
      explicitSave: true,
      defaultLayouts: [
        {title: 'Layout 1', active: true, defaultWidgets: []}
      ]
    };
    $log.debug('layoutOptions =',$scope.layoutOptions);
  });
```

**Result**

```
layoutOptions: Object{defaultLayouts:Array[1],
defaultWidgets:Array[0],
explicitSave:true,
storage:Storage,
storageHash:'fs4df4d51',
storageId: 'demo-layouts-explicit-save', 
widgetDefinitions: Array[3]}
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property '$$hashKey' of undefined
>       at Object.extend (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:406:14)
>       at Object.LayoutStorage (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/malhar-angular-dashboard/dist/malhar-angular-dashboard.js:1064:15)

I searched at line 2: Object.LayoutStorage and I found out this:

```
  angular.extend(defaults, options); //options = undefined (should have some keys and my widgetDefinitions array)
  angular.extend(options, defaults);
```

The **options** variable is undefined only when I want to setup the **$scope.layoutOptions** within the **then** callback function.
Any advice how to set / avoid this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `dashboard-layouts` directive will compile before the asynchronous call from `OtherService` has finished, which means `$scope.layoutOptions` will be `undefined`.

A simple solution is to prevent the `dashboard-layouts` directive from compiling before `$scope.layoutOptions` is available.

You can do this by using `ng-if`:

```
<div ng-if="layoutOptions" dashboard-layouts="layoutOptions" class="dashboard-container">
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)